# Design decisions behind MUI X components (number of rows below datagrid)

Tags: user-interface, material-ui, user-experience, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

MUI is said to be a module based on the results of UI/UX research. Are the design decisions for components written down accordingly? I couldn't find them. Specifically for now, I wondered why the "number of rows" below the MUI DataGrid is displayed this way.